# using multiple submit buttons in a form

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a form with two button .I want to redirect to two different pages when i click these button.On the click event of both buttons i am executing a same function.I want that the function should be executed first then it should be redirected to respective page

Comment: I can use the PHP stuff but i want to solve it through JS ore any ather way

Comment: Could you show what you have already, preferably on http://jsfiddle.net please?

Comment: Do you want the POST to be submitted to two different pages?  Or do you want to just do an AJAX call and then directly navigate to the new page?

Comment: What is `function(1)` supposed to do? `function` is a reserved JavaScript keyword and as such cannot be used as a function name.

Comment: no i want to use POST method beacuse i am using some variables value in next page

Comment: OOps i must use change(1) here...HEadache ...:\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could change action of form on the fly during submitting (and answer varies depending on using jquery, pure javascript etc.)

but I recommend using php for that task

```
<input type="submit" value="Edit" class="spare" name="edit">
<input type="submit" value="Send" class="spare" name="send">
```

and then:

```
if (isset($_POST['edit']))
    ...
elseif(isset($_POST['send']))
    ...
```

Comment: Good solution.  I was thinking change the action on the fly but have the initial default action point at some PHP script that can decipher which page you want to go to incase the user has js disabled.

Comment: Thanx Jacek but i donot want to use php stuff tehre I just want to do this through javascript

Comment: You'd better use `if(isset($_POST['edit'])){...}` if using php. Your code would raise an undefined index notice on dev platforms.

Comment: Exactly Endophage i am doing the same thing php to use window.href.location="someurl" but its not working...:(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  <input type="button" value="Edit" class="spare" onclick="check('edit')">
  <input type="button" value="Send" class="spare" onclick="check('send')">
```

Where with `check()` will add the action to the form and then submit it:

```
function check(action){
   var form = document.getElementById('formId');
   form.action = 'http://needed/url/' + action;
   form.submit();
}
```

Hope it solves your problem :)

Comment: But I'd not use this since the logic should be mainly on the server side.